# Use the definition of a limit to prove that $\lim_{y \to 0} y^3 = 0$.

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Attempt:

The limit $\lim_{y \to 0} y^3 = 0$ exists if:

$$\forall\ \epsilon >0 \ \exists\ \delta >0 \ \forall y \ |y-0|  < \delta \Longrightarrow |y^3 - 0|< \epsilon.$$

Now, I came up with the idea to use $\delta=\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}$. Would this be allowed and would it work?

Comment: Yes, that is correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, we can check this. Let $|y-0| < \delta$, i.e. $|y| < \sqrt[3]\varepsilon$. Then

$$|y^3 - 0| = |y^3|=|y|^3 < (\sqrt[3]\varepsilon)^3 = \varepsilon$$

verifying the claim.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*